# Setting element text seems to be too slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a hover event setting off a number of recursive calls (using `setTimeout`) to a function called `wobbleRadius` which effects that element's css style. Numerous of these hover events set off and they all work fine.

However, once I added in a countdown timer which updates a `<p>` element every second I get a problem. 
Every time the countdown timeout goes off the hover-effect stops working for an observable period of time, I know this is because the update to the text takes a long time as if I comment out the updating text line the wobble effect still works fine. My question is, is there a faster way to update the text value inside my `<p>` tag than:

```
$("#pText").text(value);
```

or

```
document.getElementById("pText").textContent = value;
```

If I use 12 divs instead of 14 the hover effect still works fine with the countdown so there seems to be some strange logic going on there that I don't understand.

In the following fiddle you can notice that as you hover over the divs they wobble but at intervals of 1 second appear to glitch for a short moment. Once the countdown timer reaches 0 the wobble effect works fine.

[jsfiddle.net/p7ssV/4](http://jsfiddle.net/p7ssV/4)

EDIT:

Note**: This is using Google Chrome. It seems to work perfectly in IE/FF.

Comment: I don't notice anything not working correctly :o

Comment: hover quickly over the area that changes colour while the countdown timer is running. You should notice that the changes to `border-radius` stall for a very very brief moment every time the update to the countdown time happens.

Comment: FYI, your "wobble" effect isn't working in Firefox, so people won't know what you're talking about unless they use the right browser.

Comment: Oh thanks. Had only been doing it in chrome so didn't know that! I'll mention that in the post so.

Comment: FF version:  http://jsfiddle.net/p7ssV/4/  Though I don't notice the mentioned delay.

Comment: That's amazing thanks @JamesMontagne :). Secondly it seems this is a Google Chrome issue. Your version works perfectly in IE too, but in Chrome the issue is observable.

Comment: I've seen issue before where Chrome is very laggy when doing a redraw of the page. Seems that it's not a JS issue, but rather their rendering engine.

Comment: This is just something purely based on a wild guess, but you could try to replace the wobble animation function with one based on requestAnimationFrame instead of timeout. It should make your animation more efficient and maybe solve the issue